# Mirroring Part of a SVN Repo to a Working Copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have read-only access to a third-party's SVN repo, which from time to time they make commits to. Let's call it http://foo.com/svn.

I would like to mirror this to a subfolder in an existing repo that I control. Let's call that http://bar.com/svn/myfork

I will be working on my own fork of their project but I would still like to bring changes they make over.

I want to mirror the third party's changes to my working copy only, so I can manage any conflicts manually before committing.

How can I do this?

- svnadmin dump/load seems to want to use entire repos.
- svnrdump wants to load changes to the repo, not the working copy.
- I can't apply a patch because the revision number in my working copy don't match the revision numbers in the patch.
- Manually copying files replaces my changes.

I am using Windows (svn and TortoiseSVN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far as I'm aware the closest feature to this is [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html); however, this stores only a relative or, in this case, absolute URL pointer to the external repository. In short, the files would not be stored in your repository and any commit attempts on the contents of the external would go to the third party repository.

I've stored check outs from other repositories in SVN where I can bring changes over from the third-party repository and commit those changes and my own changes to my own repository (a private fork) when the third-party repositories were accessible through git or mercurial. I would check the third party repositories out into my SVN working directory and commit everything to SVN including the `.hg`/`.git` folders. This approach, whilst undoubtedly a bit hacky, worked for me and would, if I understand your question correctly, work for you too *if* one of the repositories were *not* SVN.

If it's not possible to access `foo` with say git or mercurial and not possible to change `bar`'s versioning system, I'm wondering if it might be possible to set up a second copy of SVN on your machine with a different environment - I'm thinking [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) - and have one of the installations store the versioning files in `.svn` and one in `_svn`. I'm guessing this will work as Cygwin's `svn` will be a seperate installation in a Unix-like folder tree with its own environment. (I've just tried it and it should work).

Steps might be:

1. Install cygwin with svn and [change Cygwin svn to use _svn folders](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/asp-dot-net-hack.txt) (I tried this in Cygwin by setting the environment variable `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK`, and it worked - you'd have to set the environment variable in bash only not at Windows-level otherwise Tortoise will pick it up too)
2. Check out the third party repository into your working copy using Cygwin `svn`
3. Commit the third party repository files, optionally including its `_svn` folder to your repository (I would include it)
4. You can now update the third party repository using Cygwin `svn` and commit the third party changes to your repository, in addition to being able to commit your own changes to your own repository. You could probably commit changes back to the third party repository too!

Another option on the same theme might be to have a second Windows account with the environment variable set, and log in to that account to initially check out the third party repository and to bring down updates from it using TSVN.